# Facebook Graph API - Story endpoint does not return all active stories

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I currently try to get once per day all stories which are posted on one of my facebook business pages.
But when I execute the request I always get only 1 story in return even when there are multiple stories posted.

I'm using the following endpoint url:

[https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{{page_id}}/stories?limit=25](https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/%7B%7Bpage_id%7D%7D/stories?limit=25)

As I get one story, I assume that this is not an authentication issue.
What could be the reason for that and do you have any proposals on how I could ensure to always receive all active stories?

Thank you!
Jannik

Comment: _"even when there are multiple stories posted"_ - and those are from within the last 24 hours?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So if I open the facebook page I can see 4 storys in total